# Extending kendo multiselect and working with MVVM

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-multiselect

I'm trying to extend a kendo multiselect so that it has a default data source as well as templates. It's all working except the pre-loaded values in the MVVM object. When I start updating the exented multiselect, the value of the MVVM gets updated, the initial items are just not pre-loaded:

```
kendo.ui.plugin(kendo.ui.MultiSelect.extend({
    init: function(element, options) {
        var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/SecurityEntities",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function(data) {
                    return {
                        prefixText: '',
                        count: 5,
                        getUsers: true,
                        getGroups: false
                    };
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function(data) {
                    console.log($.parseJSON(data));
                    return $.parseJSON(data);
                }
            }
        });
        options = options == null ? {} : options;
        options.itemTemplate = "...";
        options.tagTemplate = "...";
        options.dataSource = ds;

        kendo.ui.MultiSelect.fn.init.call(this, element, options);
    },
    options: {
        name: 'EntityMultiSelect'
    }
}));

kendo.data.binders.widget.entitymultiselect = 
kendo.data.binders.widget.multiselect;
```

Then my html is:

```
<div data-bind="value: machine.Managers" data-role="entitymultiselect" 
     data-delay="400" data-animation="false" 
     data-placeholder="Select users to notify"></div>
```

And I am binding the whole container to the page's viewModel object.

I've seen other people have issues with this very problem and added the

```
kendo.data.binders.widget.entitymultiselect = 
    kendo.data.binders.widget.multiselect;
```

**(And yes that does seem like a bug)**

But it still doesn't work.

When there are already values in Machine.Managers, it doesn't load them. However, if I add values to the multiselect, they get added to Machine.Managers .

**EDIT:**

I've added a live [example](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/eYIq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in your demo it's a trivial problem: your `data-value-field` is wrong. As a result, the binder can't match the selected elements.

Instead of

```
<div data-role="entitymultiselect" 
 data-bind="value: selected" 
 data-value-field="ProductId"></div>
```

you need

```
<div data-role="entitymultiselect" 
 data-bind="value: selected" 
 data-value-field="ProductID"></div>
```

([working demo](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/aHiB))

Since you're not defining the value field in the code in your question, it might be the same issue.

Comment: doh! thanks, that does fix that, unfortunately, it doesn't fix it in my actual code, my datasource is an constantly reading to the web service for entries, unlike this one which seems to get all the entries at once...

Comment: why is it constantly reading? can you try to break the demo again? it's hard to figure out what's wrong without debugging it

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to break it again -- by constantly reading I meant that it fetches data on demand.... So when someone enters Matt, it will  fetch 10 Matts, whereas if someone entered Dan, it would fetch 10 Dans

Comment: So I'm pretty sure that it's breaking in my code because instead of odata like in the example, my data source is JSON. Do you know if telerik has a sample JSON datasource up for consumption?

Comment: Yeah, in fact, if you try it without a datasource it also breaks.. Same as multiselct http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@mdufrasne/ivAn, so that must be it.

Comment: if you don't have a DS then it can't work because there are no elements to match at all (the elements in selected will only be selected in the widget if there is currently an item in the data source with matching ProductID); found a json endpoint and created demo with that: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/ewuT

Comment: Right, but until I let the user add new ones and need to fetch records from the server, if I have the preloaded ones which I already obtained though other calls. I thought the control would render them in the box, especially since I'm not using the data-value primitive option. I guess I was wrong and this can probably not work.

Comment: you could try making transport.read a function and adding the default entries to the data before calling options.success so they always exist in the DS

Comment: That's a great idea! Let me try that now.

Comment: Didn't work.... I'll give you the bounty points for the help -- sucks that you need the items to be in the DS to preload, especially if your DS is on demand.

Comment: curious why it didn't work; tried it here and it seems to work: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/ewuT

Comment: Bounty award -- thanks! I guess what doesn't quite work in the example is that in the datasource, you are adding the items directly instead of reference to them; how could I get the value from the options parameter. Not sure if that makes sense? But I agree, that's the last bit.

Comment: the widget doesn't have a direct reference to the view model, so that's probably not the best way to do it; depending on where your defaults come from, maybe you could simply store them in a global object? or you could add a data-defaults="["a", "b"]" attribute and then read that in the init method from $(element)